# How to plot a point in gnuplot with x-coordinate from file and y coordinate based on a test condition?

Tags: awk, plot, gnuplot

I have a file containing data in 3 columns. The first column contains x-coordinates and the third column contains y-coordinates. The second column contains values (as an example, lets say it has values from the set `{0, 1, 2}`) depending on which, the colour and type of the plotted point is decided. I am using the following command to do the plotting:

```
plot "< awk '{if($2 == \"0\") print}' out.txt" using 1:3 title "Label 0" with points pointtype 1 lc rgb '#990000'  
     "< awk '{if($2 == \"1\") print}' out.txt" using 1:3 title "Label 1" with points pointtype 2 lc rgb '#990055'  
     "< awk '{if($2 == \"2\") print}' out.txt" using 1:3 title "Label 2" with points pointtype 3 lc rgb '#990099'
```

This works fine. But now, I want to achieve the following:

- If for a certain row, the `(1st column, 3rd column)` in my file corresponds to `(xi, yi)`, then depending on the value of `yi`, I wish to plot a point at `(xi, Yi)`.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.
PS: I am a beginner in gnuplot. I am not sure if its a very simple question.
Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of the sample data and my expectations.

```
Sample Data:                                  Expected point:

0 0 34                                        (0, 30) Red   
0 1 10                                        (0, 10) Green  
0 2 44                                        (0, 40) Blue
1 0 50                                        (1, 50) Red
1 1 49                                        (1, 50) Green
1 2 48                                        (1, 50) Blue
2 0 46                                        (2, 50) Red
2 1 49                                        (2, 50) Green
2 2 46                                        (2, 50) Blue
3 0 45                                        (3, 50) Red
3 1 46                                        (3, 50) Green
3 2 48                                        (3, 50) Blue
4 0 68                                        (4, 70) Red
4 1 44                                        (4, 40) Green
4 2 46                                        (4, 50) Blue
5 0 43                                        (5, 40) Red
5 1 44                                        (5, 40) Green
5 2 44                                        (5, 40) Blue
6 0 43                                        (6, 40) Red
6 1 42                                        (6, 40) Green
6 2 46                                        (6, 50) Blue
```

Comment: How is `Yi` determined from `yi`?

Comment: @Tom Fenech, `Yi` may be derived from `yi` via some simple calculation or it may be a constant. Like, if the values in the file are (5, 0, 73), (6, 1, 78), (7, 2, 84), I would want to choose `Yi` as 80 (a constant) or the nearest multiple of 10, for each `yi`.

Comment: Based on your comment, it seems that you're suggesting that the lines are grouped into three - is that the case? If so, and you want to use a number based on the average value rounded to the nearest 10 (or something like that), things get a little more complicated. If you just wanted to round the numbers to the nearest 10, that would be easy enough. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Showing some sample data is always useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think that you need to use awk in your current code. A common trick to skip rows in gnuplot is to use a ternary operator like this:

```
plot 'out.txt' using ($2 == 0 ? $1 : 1/0):3 title "Label 0" with points pointtype 1 lc rgb '#990000'
```

The `x` coordinate is set to `1/0` (i.e. `inf`) unless the value in the second column is `0`, which means that the data point is skipped.

If you want to plot a completely different `y` coordinate for a given `(x, y)` pair, you could use something like this:

```
x = 4
y = 2
Y = 10
plot 'out.txt' using ($2 == 0 ? $1 : 1/0):($1 == x && $3 == y ? Y : $3) title "Label 0" with points pointtype 1 lc rgb '#990000'
```

As before, the line is skipped when the second column doesn't match the required value. I've also added a condition that when the first and third column match the variables `x` and `y`, the value of `Y` is used instead of the third column.

To perform a calculation based on the current value of `y`, you could use a function `f(y)` rather than a variable `Y`. For example, to round to the nearest value of 10, you could declare this function:

```
f(y) = round(y / 10) * 10
```

then replace `Y` with `f($3)`.

As an aside, the structure of an awk program is `condition { action }` and the default action is `{ print }` so if you were going to use awk, you could simplify to `awk '$2 == 0'` (it's also unnecessary to quote the `0`).

Comment: Thank you for the elegant answer. Could you tell me if there is an easy way to do some 'minor' calculations with `$3` and get value for `Y`? Like `Y = nearest_multiple_of_ten(y)` or `Y=y-y|mod 10|`.

Comment: @jsp99 edited to show an example of a function. Hope that helps.

Comment: The most elegant solution to the problem. Thank you.